# How to pass disabled textbox value in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How may i pass disabled textbox value on controller side ?

Right now i am getting nil value for the disabled textbox.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is an http thing, if you disable a form element it does not get sent over the wire. You can either set the `readonly='true'` attribute with javascript and style it to *appear* disabled, or use javascript to copy the value to a hidden field. unfortunately, you there is no way to just tell it to send.